# HTTP Post Request check in swift

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

i have php file to check a value passed from swift ios, i print json data, this is the code:

```
<?php
$said = $_REQUEST['sa_id'];
if($said == '123456') {
    $returnValue = array("said" => "true");
}else{
    $returnValue = array("said" => "false");
}
echo json_encode($returnValue);
?>
```

Also i wrote a swift function to check the returned said value, my code is work success in second click, i want it from first click:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var saidResult = false;

    @IBOutlet var saidField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var labelField: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }   

    @IBAction func checkSAID(sender: UIButton) {

        if ( isValidSAID(saidField.text) == false ) {
            labelField.text = "SAID is Invalid"
        } else {
            labelField.text = "Done"
        }
    }

    func isValidSAID(said2Test: String) -> Bool {

        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://*****.com/said.php");
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

        // Compose a query string
        let postString = "sa_id=\(said2Test)";

        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                println("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            println("response = \(response)")

            // Print out response body
            let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("responseString = \(responseString)")

            //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
            var err: NSError?
            var myJSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error:&err) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON =myJSON {
                // Now we can access value of First Name by its key
                var saidValue = parseJSON["said"] as? String
                println("saidValue: \(saidValue)")

                if ((saidValue) == "true" ) {
                    self.saidResult = true;
                }

                println("saidResult: \(self.saidResult)");
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        println("saidResult: \(self.saidResult)");
        if ( self.saidResult == true ){
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }

    }

}
```

As i say, in first click the value of saidResult is false but after that it is take the true value

How i can solve this issue, or is there another way to improve my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after 4 days of testing i solved my problem.

I changed isValidSAID function code:

```
func isValidSAID(said2Test: String) -> Bool {

    var status: String = "";

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://*****.com/said.php?sa_id=\(said2Test)");
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: myUrl!)
    let json = NSHSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, option: nil, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

    status = (json["said"] as? String)!
    println(status)

    return ( status == "true" ) ? true : false
}
```

and solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably because the http request is not answered on the first click but is on the second click.

you could try replacing your checkSAID function with this.

```
@IBAction func checkSAID(sender: UIButton) {

    let saidQueue = dispatch_queue_create("saidQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)

    // Do the checking on a background thread.
    dispatch_async(saidQueue, {
        if ( isValidSAID(saidField.text) == false ) {
    // As the UI updates are performed on the main queue, update the label on the main queue.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                labelField.text = "SAID is Invalid"
            })
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                labelField.text = "Done"
            })
        }
    })

}
```